# How to handle a `@user.errors` JSON data when the AJAX HTTP request returns an `error`?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails v3.0.9 and jQuery v1.6.1. I would like to handle (by using jQuery) a JSON response data when the AJAX HTTP request returns an `error` (see the code below for more information) in order to display `@user.errors` messages. That is, ...

... in the controller I have:

```
render :json   => @user.errors,
       :status => 400
```

... in the view file I have:

```
$jQ.ajax({
  type:     '...',
  url:      '...',
  dataType: 'json',
  data:     '...',
  error:    function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    // Here is where I would like to handle the above mentioned `@user.errors` 
    // array (that is related to the "Ruby on Rails Way" of handling errors).
    //
    // I tried to use 'alert(jqXHR.base);' but the `@user.errors` array is always
    // returned as a string.
    alert(...)

  },
  success:  function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    ...
  }
});
```

**There is a way to change the above code so to use something like the following in order to display errors?**

```
# Supposing that'@user.errors' is '{"base":["already exist"]}'
alert(jqXHR.base);
```

Note: In few words, I would like to handle data as made when I get a success AJAX HTTP request data (`function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)`'s permits me to use the JSON parsed `data` like so: `alert(jqXHR.base);`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple. You just need to json-decode the answer returned by the server. Simply use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/ to do that.